# Commerce Donation page

Tags: commerce

I want to create a button on each node to a donation page. The button needs to send the title of the node to that page, I have managed to do this.

I have a product type ***donation***. I modify the form price with line item and setup a form where you can select different donations values.

The problem is that I need to find a way to include that title in the donation form so It can be passed to cart.

I have tried commerce add to cart function to alter that, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Made a Product Type: Donation
2. After that I created Products of: 2 USD, 10 USD etc.
3. Created a donation page of form: `/donation/*`
4. When I reference the donation page from the node page the links look like this: `/donation/%nid`
5. On the donation page I create a custom form and there I modify the submit function.